# Problem with puenc.def

Tags: texorpdfstring

I have a LaTeX file processed last with texlive-2021. In this file I used

```
\input{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def}
```

to define `\textsigma`, `\textzeroinferior`, `\textasciicircum` etc in `\texorpdfstring`

and it worked perfectly. This distribution is no longer available.

Trying to skip it, or replace it with

```
\input{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def},
```

or

```
\input{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def}
```

results in different error messages.

---

The minimal example

```latex
\documentclass[13pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\input{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def}

\begin{document}

\section{Test \texorpdfstring{$\alpha$}{\textalpha}}

\end{document}
```

In this case it reports an error

```
3: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

l.293 \providedcommand*\update@u
              clc@with@greek{%
 ?
```

However running it twice in "force mode" produces required bookmark Test "alpha" (with greek symbol alpha) but also unwanted

```
uclc@with@greekuclc@with@greek @@uclc@with@greek
ifnextchar[3]d= 1let@tokenfnch ifnch@b
```

in pdf.

Commenting line with `puenc.def` produces an error
`Undefined control sequence`.

Comment: There should be no need to load puenc.def manually, hyperref will load it anyway. And it would help you would mention which errors you get. Or at least show a minimal example how you use that so that one can try to reproduce.

Comment: \textle , \textin, \textint in \texorpdfstring do not require puenc.def. But Greek letters require. Not sure about  other symbols

Comment: Use `\usepackage[psdextra]{hyperref}`.

Comment: Or define `\textBeta` before loading hyperref, then hyperref will load greek support.

Comment: > \usepackage[psdextra]{hyperref}     

Thanks, Ulrike,

Worked like a charm––both in the minimal example and the real file

Comment: @UlrikeFischer An answer?